# Working with ARKit in function to change SCNNode is making app stop running

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I am working on an ARKit project in Swift Playgrounds and here is what I have right now:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.animateSoldiers), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


@objc func animateSoldiers() {
  if self.soldiersPlacedCount >= self.numberOfSoldiers {
      for node in self.allNodesSet {
          if node.name!.contains("soldier") {
              node.position = SCNVector3(x: node.position.x + 0.01, y: node.position.y, z: node.position.z)

              let pitch = sceneView.session.currentFrame?.camera.eulerAngles.x
              let yawn = sceneView.session.currentFrame?.camera.eulerAngles.y
              let roll = sceneView.session.currentFrame?.camera.eulerAngles.z
              let newRotation = SCNVector3Make(pitch!, yawn!, roll!)
              node.eulerAngles = newRotation
          }
      }
  }
}
```

I have narrowed down the issue to this method. The app crashes after running an arbitrary number of times when running on iPad. It keeps changing and I have no idea what is going on. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a Timer, implement this ARSessionDelegate method:

`session(_:didUpdate:)`

This method is called every time a new frame is generated, as far as the AR session is running, working as a loop.

My advice is to use this to animate SCNNodes, never use timers. Having 60 frames per second, it will be equivalent to a Timer triggered every 16 milliseconds approx.

Also, with this method you make sure that in every frame you have a new position for the node. Timers are not stable and aren't synchronized with the frames, they don't give a fluid animation to SCNNodes.

Don't forget to set the delegate of the session:

```
sceneView.session.delegate = self
```